# After upgrading Fedora, why can I no longer change permissions of a file mounted via SMB

Tags: windows, linux, permissions, samba, smb

I had been running Fedora 9 for the last year --- I have a Windows box (actually a VM) that mounts a folder on the Fedora box using my own name/password. I do this so that I can run my version control program (Vault) on Windows. It has worked flawlessly for the last 6 months.

Yesterday, I upgraded Fedora from version 9 to version 11. Since doing so, I am no longer able to change file permissions from my Windows box. Nothing has changed, there's no firewall on the machine, SELinux is disabled (SELINUX=disabled in /etc/sysconfig/selinux), etc

I can still read the files.  Any idea what has happened and how I might fix this?

Thanks,
David

P.S.  The error I get is

An error occurred applying attributes to the file:
....my filename...
Access is denied.

P.P.S.   I AM able to create a NEW file in the mounted folder. After doing so, I can change its properties to make it be read-only. BUT I then can NOT change its properties again to be writable.  Hope this helps.

Comment: One more interesting note --- if I mount the linux folder on my macintosh over SMB, I have no problems changing permissions from my macintosh. So this is ONLY an issue with accessing the mounted folder from Windows (and I've reproduced this on two different windows machines).

Could it have something to do with Window ACLs?

Comment: This probably belongs on www.superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this would appear to be a bug in the latest version of Samba that you get when you install Fedora 11.

I manually built SAMBA 3.4.1 from source, installed it and my Windows machines work just fine with it.

(Just in case anyone else searches this site)